# Azure function (HttpTrigger) exception when referencing a .NET standard class library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using the WebJob SDK to create an Azure Function in Visual Studio 2017 (specifically an outgoing Slack WebHook).

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log)
```

I can debug the function locally, and execute it successfully.

I then add a reference to a **new** .NET standard class library, compile and debug, and upon triggering the function, am presented with the following error.

```
{
  "id": "2badc751-bd37-4482-90db-6dde1247110c",
  "requestId": "60acb725-546e-4e62-9868-a5bd4c217bfc",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Exception while executing function: SlackWebHooks -> Exception binding parameter 'req' -> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.",
  "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: SlackWebHooks ---> System.InvalidOperationException : Exception binding parameter 'req' ---> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException : No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content,Type type,IEnumerable`1 formatters,IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.HttpTriggerBinding.CreateUserTypeValueProvider(HttpRequestMessage request,String invokeString)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.HttpTriggerBinding.BindAsync(Object value,ValueBindingContext context)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.TriggeredFunctionBinding`1.BindCoreAsync[TTriggerValue](ValueBindingContext context,Object value,IDictionary`2 parameters) \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,FunctionDescriptor function,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

I'm unsure as to why referencing the .NET standard library would change the behaviour of the SDK? But it's apparent it's related to `MediaTypeFormatter`, or there lack of.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1792?

Comment: I encountered the similar issue when I use `await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();` for getting request body in my HttpTrigger function app, while the request header has the `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a similar issue that I had with a conflict between System.Net.Http and other libraries that use the HttpRequest Extensions. See this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271133/httprequestmessageextensions-not-being-found-at-run-time-in-azure-function/46015787#46015787)

I tried downgrading the version on System.Net.Http all the way to 4.0.0, which was the only one that allowed my app to work. I still got a warning about conflicting System.Net.Http version requirements, but it didn't seem to impact anything (saving that discussion for my topic I linked). One poster mentioned that for him, 4.3.1 not the newest 4.3.2 fixed the problem. Others mentioned they were able to remove System.Net.Http entirely as the extensions were being included by other packages. In my case, I can't remove it as I'm using SendGrid which prevents me from doing so. Might want to try removing it or if you can't, stepping down on the version.